# Show alert message when clicking on text box set in MasterPage in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to check whether the `TextBox` is disabled or not.

If we try to click on the disabled `TextBox`. It should show an alert message.

This is my code with source http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/2kwKc/ but in my case not working.

On **MasterPage.master** :

```
<asp: ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp: ContentPlaceHolder > 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#txDateRet").click(function () {
        if (this.readOnly) {
        alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
}); 
</script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

On **Markup** `Default.aspx` webpage:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txDateRet" runat="server" 
    ReadOnly="true" BackColor="Yellow" 
    Width="300" CssClass="toUpper"
    Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

**#Update #1**

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txDateRet").click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("readonly") == "readonly") {
                    alert($(this).attr("readonly"));
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


<asp:TextBox ID="txDateRet" 
     ClientIDMode="Static" 
     runat="server" 
     ReadOnly="true" 
     BackColor="Yellow" 
     Width="300" 
     CssClass="toUpper"
     Enabled="false">
</asp:TextBox>
```

**#Update #2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#txDateRet").click(function () { 
                alert($(this).attr("readonly"));


    });
});
```

**#Update #3**

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txDateRet" 
             type="text" value="26/02/2019" 
             readonly="readonly" 
             id="txDateRet" 
             class="toUpper" 
             style="background-color:Yellow;width:300px;" />           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `ClientIDMode = static` on your text box.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for help but the alert not show.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element to see what the ID is when it's rendered? Also load you jQuery library before you click event otherwise you'll get the `$` is undefined error

Comment: please update the post with the generated html by inspecting the asp element using browser inspector

Comment: `txDateRet` may get different `ID` after rendering, inspect element and see what ID that got, or use `$('#<%=txDateRet.ClientID%>')`

Comment: @Aria I have this error CS0103: The name txDateRet don't exists

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland, Isn't  value of `readonly` prop will be "readonly" ? like reason 3 in my answer ? something like `readonly="readonly"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are may three reasons:
1- Because that code rendered before loading `JQuery` library so put that script before triggering `click` event.

2- Because that element is and ASP.Net element in a place holder, it may will get different ID that you can see it by inspecting it.

totally change the code like:

```
<asp: ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp: ContentPlaceHolder > 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txDateRet").click(function () {
        if (this.readOnly) {
        alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
   });
}); 
</script> 

<asp:TextBox ID="txDateRet" ClientIDMode = "static" runat="server" 
    ReadOnly="true" BackColor="Yellow" 
    Width="300" CssClass="toUpper"
    Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

3- Or that `readonly` prop will not get `true` after rendering it may will get `readonly="readonly"` so `if (this.readOnly)` will not work, it may should changed to `if (this.readOnly == "readonly")`.

hope this answer give you the clue.

Comment: How about this `if($("#txDateRet").attr("readonly") == "readonly")` or `if($(this).attr("readonly") == "readonly")` .

Comment: please alert `readonly` property before `if` condition and see what prompted, like `alert($(this).attr("readonly"))` ?

Comment: please see my **#Update #1** in my post

Comment: I said alert `readonly` prop before `if` condition so please try this  `$("#txDateRet").click(function () {
                 alert($(this).attr("readonly")); // here is if condition
            });` and tell the feedback.

Comment: please see my **#Update #2** in my post ... I'm not sure I understand but no alert

Comment: So you sure there is no any alert when you clicked on `textbox` if yes, the I am sure that `click` event will not fired so pleas right click on `textbox` in browser ant then click inspect and see what is the id of TextBox and what is the readonly value.

Comment: Why `Enabled="false"` ? try to change it to `Enabled="true"` and try again.

Comment: Did you inspected text box to see the ID, isn't there error log in console of you browser ?

Comment: In my first question on **#Update #3** I have posted HTML output in the browser **IE 11**

Comment: The Id is correct but there may be some bugs in browser console, please try this `$('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txDateRet"]').click` instead of `$("#txDateRet").click`, try it in Chrome also .

Comment: Change `$("#txDateRet").click` to  `$('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txDateRet"]').clic` and tried it in Chrome also without success ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189119/discussion-between-aria-and-chevy-mark-sunderland).

Answer (score 0):

I think in `webform` we give the complete id of `textbox` with content place holder.
You can try this.

```
$("#head_txDateRet").click(function () {
   if (this.readOnly) {
      alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the comments in your question, you should include the jquery reference before actually using it.@ChevyMarkSunderland

Comment: $(this).attr("readonly"); Try to add this and console log this